# CTE data conversion error - Fine with temp tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression, type-conversion

So, I have a CTE that's throwing the error: `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type nvarchar to float.`  The problem is that if I break down the CTE into temp tables, everything runs fine!

Below is a slight simplification of what I'm doing (data types are accurate, I just renamed things, created bogus data, removed a couple extra joins and where clauses that don't seem to effect the error, etc.)... note that this sample does work correctly, which just adds to my confusion:

```
--Build and populate sample data
create table vals
(
    groupID int,
    valName nvarchar(50),
    val     nvarchar(50)
)
insert into vals(groupID, valName, val)
select 1, 'setting1', '12:00' union
select 1, 'setting2', '18:00' union
select 1, 'setting3', '3.2' union
select 2, 'setting1', '9:00' union
select 2, 'setting3', '4' union
select 2, 'setting5', 'steve'

create table collected
(
    groupID int,
    timeUTC datetime,
    collected float
)
insert into collected(groupID, timeUTC, collected)
select 1, '2012-09-12 18:00', 2.8 union
select 1, '2012-09-12 18:30', 3.0 union
select 1, '2012-09-12 19:00', 3.3 union
select 1, '2012-09-12 19:30', 4.0 union
select 1, '2012-09-12 20:00', 2.5 union
select 2, '2012-09-12 18:00', 3.5 union
select 2, '2012-09-12 18:30', 3.9 union
select 2, '2012-09-12 19:00', 4.6 union
select 2, '2012-09-12 19:30', 4.2 union
select 2, '2012-09-12 20:00', 4.3


--Here's the CTE that errors on the actual dataset
;with triggerVal as (
    select groupID,
        [trg] = min(cast(val as float))
    from vals
    where valName = 'setting3'
    group by groupID
), currentVal as (
    select c.groupID, c.timeUTC,
        [curr] = c.collected
    from collected c
        join (
            select groupID, [lastTime] = max(timeUTC)
            from collected
            group by groupID
        ) l on c.groupID=l.groupID
            and c.timeUTC = l.lastTime
)
select t.groupID, c.timeUTC, t.trg, c.curr
from triggerVal t
    join currentVal c on t.groupID=c.groupID
```

Again, in my live data, if I break the above CTE into temp tables (`#triggerVal` and `#currentVal`) everything runs fine.  While it's not the end of the world for me to modify my code, I'd really like to understand what's happening!

Comment: You can't control the order that SQL will evaluate your CTEs. So your WHERE clause (which should limit the output to only numeric values) is happening later than you think, and SQL Server is coming upon the value 'steve' and trying to convert it to a float. You can't rely on short-circuiting of a where clause, even with a nested CTE. The only solution I know of in some cases is to completely isolate the queries as you've done. There might be other ways to ensure it doesn't happen in your case, but probably safest to re-write it until the optimizer gets smarter or guarantees short-circuiting.

Comment: As a side note, I could not reproduce your error message on SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012. Not saying it's a reason to upgrade, but...

Comment: Yeah, I can't duplicate the error with a different table... So, I'm not sure the version of SQL Server has anything to do with it...